# Ktor: define route for URL with and without tailing slash

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to learn Ktor, when responding to a GET request, I found that the trailing slash is treated as two routes, for example:

```
/greet?name=john
/greet/?name=john
```

Is it possible to define one route for the above two URLs, which is to handle trailing slash automatically?

Comment: hi, perhaps use `IgnoreTrailingSlash` or a pattern match https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-372

Answer (score 8):

In your `Application.module()` or `Application.configureRouting()` add this:

```kotlin
install(IgnoreTrailingSlash)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [IgnoreTrailingSlash](https://ktor.io/docs/routing-in-ktor.html#match_url) plugin to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using install(IgnoreTrailingSlash) with static content, as omitting the trailing slash will result in a base url without the final path segment.

For example, let's say I have something like this in my routing code...

```
staticResources("/static", "static")
get("/myendpoint")
```

And an html file, which imports some javascript...

```
<script type="module" src="static/index.js"></script>
```

The import will fail with the trailing slash.